# How to group duplicates? Lambda 8 Java

Tags: java, lambda

I'm near to the final output of this homework program. I can't figure out how to group the duplicate cityName together. For example in this case "Tennessee Colony".

Here's the sample output:

```
    County Name             County Pop          City Name               City Pop.           No. Zip Codes   
    Anderson County         41169               Cayuga                  199                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Elkhart                 4460                    1      
    Anderson County         41169               Frankston               4830                    1      
    Anderson County         41169               Montalba                850                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Neches                  484                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Palestine               28771                   4      
    Anderson County         41169               Palestine               28771                   4      
    Anderson County         41169               Palestine               28771                   4      
    Anderson County         41169               Palestine               28771                   4      
    Anderson County         41169               Tennessee Colony        1575                    4      
    Anderson County         41169               Tennessee Colony        1575                    4      
    Anderson County         41169               Tennessee Colony        1575                    4      
    Anderson County         41169               Tennessee Colony        1575                    4
```

and i want it to be like this:

```
    County Name             County Pop          City Name               City Pop.           No. Zip Codes   
    Anderson County         41169               Cayuga                  199                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Elkhart                 4460                    1      
    Anderson County         41169               Frankston               4830                    1      
    Anderson County         41169               Montalba                850                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Neches                  484                     1      
    Anderson County         41169               Palestine               28771                   4          
    Anderson County         41169               Tennessee Colony        1575                    4
```

Note: This program requires getting the data from an excel file and output it like this.

Here is a part of my code:

```
    texasCArray.sort(Comparator.comparing(zipCodeClass::getcountyName)
               .thenComparing(zipCodeClass::getcityName)
               .thenComparing(zipCodeClass::getestPop)
               .thenComparing(zipCodeClass::getzipCode)
               .thenComparing(zipCodeClass::gettypeZip));

    texasCArray.stream()
        .sorted( (txc1,txc2) -> txc1.getcountyName().compareTo(txc2.getcountyName()))
        .forEach( p -> {

            long totalCountyPop = texasCArray.stream()
                    .filter(txc -> txc.getcountyName().equals(p.getcountyName()))
                    .map(txc -> txc.getestPop())
                    .reduce(0, Integer::sum);

            long totalCityPop = texasCArray.stream()
                    .filter(txc -> txc.getcountyName().equals(p.getcountyName()))
                    .filter(txc -> txc.getcityName().equals(p.getcityName()))
                    .map(txc -> txc.getestPop())
                    .reduce(0, Integer::sum);

            long countZipCodes = texasCArray.stream()
                    .filter(txc -> txc.getcountyName().equals(p.getcountyName()))
                    .filter(txc -> txc.getcityName().equals(p.getcityName())) // filter out cities for each county
                    .count();

            out.printf("%-19s\t\t%-10d\t\t\t%-20s\t%-15d\t\t\t%-7d\n", p.getcountyName(), 
                    totalCountyPop, p.getcityName(),totalCityPop, countZipCodes);
        });
```

I really appreciate if anyone could help me point out how I can approach this. Thanks.

Comment: 1. It's not "grouping" - what you want to do is remove duplicate records. 2. It's difficult to help you since you don't show us how `texasCArray` is constructed, how its objects look like and etc.

Answer (score 2):

step1 ensure the class override equals and hashcode

then get a stream fromthe collection of texasCArray, get from those the **distinct** and collect to something like a list

```
List<Integer> myL = new ArrayList<>();
myL.add(1);
myL.add(1);
myL.add(10);
myL.add(10);
myL.add(1);
myL.add(33);
myL.add(33);
System.out.println(myL.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

the result will just discard the duplicated and the output will be

[1, 10, 33]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the class of the objects in `texasCArray` overrides `equals` and `hashCode` methods in a way that such duplicate objects will be considered equal.

Then all you have to do it copy these objects from `texasCArray` into a set (use `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`) and all your duplicates will be removed.

Comment: *"you can use `HashSet` for example"* Saying "for example" makes it sound like you can choose any `Set` implementation, but that's not true, since a `TreeSet` wouldn't work just by implementing `equals` and `hashCode`. A better suggestion would be to use `LinkedHashSet`, since it seems desirable to retain the original order from the sorted `texasCArray`.

Comment: @Andreas what about SortedSet? and why do you think it's important to keep a certain order?

Comment: Sure, a `SortedSet` (like `TreeSet`) would be good, but that negates the need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`, and your answer starts out saying you have to implement them, ergo your answer is setting it up specifically to use a hash-based `Set`.

Comment: @Andreas sorry but I don't understand your point. All the sets you mentioned will remove duplicates only if the objects are considered `equals` and have the same hashCode. No?

Comment: No, `TreeSet` doesn't use `equals` at all. Or `hashCode`. It *only* uses the comparison method, either the `compareTo` of the implemented `Comparable`, or the `compare` of the supplied `Comparator`.

Comment: hmmm I see, it compares, so in that case the OP will have to implement Comparable. Good point.

Comment: I guess that it's up to the OP to decide which implementation of Set will be more suitable (since this is a context we don't have...).